# App Engine Downloads .PHP Files

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, wordpress-theming

My Wordpress site's theme on PHP App Engine contains a `.css.php` file.  On normal hosting, when you navigate to the url of this file, the browser displays a page of CSS.  On App Engine, the browser downloads the PHP file.

I would guess this is a problem with `app.yaml` - but specifically, what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made to the Google tutorial's app.yaml to fix the Wordpress install:

```
handlers:
- url: /wp-content/themes/fuse/library/css/custom.css.php
  script: wordpress/wp-content/themes/fuse/library/css/custom.css.php

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|ttf$|jpg$|jpeg$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|ttf$|jpg$|jpeg$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|ttf$|jpeg$|htm$|html$|css$|js$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|ttf$|jpeg$|htm$|html$|css$|js$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|ttf$|jpeg$|htm$|html$|css$|js$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|ttf$|jpeg$|htm$|html$|css$|js$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
```

I just enabled a few more types of static files (like otf and svg) and allowed a PHP file in the theme to run as a script rather than download as a static file.

Answer (score 1):

Does your app.yaml file look like the one in the [tutorial site](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress).

Comment: Yes, when I asked this I was using that tutorial's app.yaml.  I ended up hiring someone to fix the problem - we had to add like 3 lines - and it was fixed